App icon does not display
I have installed the highly-regarded Solflare app (com.solflare.mobile) on a rather ordinary Android 7 device (the app supposedly supports Android 6 and later). Instead of the correct icon for the app, I see only the generic green android icon (on both the desktop, and any application that lists apps, such as Settings).
This annoys me greatly for two reasons:

I have over 100 other apps installed on this device, and not one of them exhibits this problem.

I contacted the developers about this, and they seem completely unconcerned (blaming my device, which has a stock ROM). Their attitude actually shocked me (why should I trust a crypto wallet if the developers don't even care about the icon displaying correctly?).


I lack the skills to troubleshoot this (or I would attempt to determine what causes this myself). I hope that someone here can explain why this happens (thank you in advance).
You can download a recent version of the .apk here (or on any other web site that hosts .apk files):
https://www.apkmonk.com/app/com.solflare.mobile/
